# My custom domain and SSL Cert missing from console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've setup a custom domain + SSL cert for a App Engine project about 2 months ago and even though the site is online and requests properly directed to this GAE app the `Application Settings` in the Console shows no custom domain and no SSL cert?!

It was there before, obviously... Any ideas?

I'll soon need to renew my certificate (is valid for 90 days) and would not want to go through the whole setup of a custom domain

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the CNAME entry to verify ownership was removed (note to self, change provider) so Google could not do it periodic verification (message on the webmaster console...). 
I would never though looking there for an issue affecting GAE!

Answer (score 0):

Under some circumstances not all users can see the custom domains - try logging in as the user you set it up with.